# Request-scoped bean is available in @RestController but throws ScopeNotActiveException in HttpFilter

Tags: java, spring, httprequest, requestscope

Recently I've run into an issue regarding request-scoped beans. Here's the code:

```java
@Configuration
class PreAuthorizationHttpHeaderFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    JwtPreAuthorizationConfigurer jwtPreAuthorizationConfigurer() {
        return new JwtPreAuthorizationConfigurer();
    }


    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    TenantContext tenantContext() {
        return new TenantContext();
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class TenantContext {
    private String tenantName;
    private String issuerUri;
    private String jwkSetUri;
}

public class JwtPreAuthorizationConfigurer extends HttpFilter {

    @Resource
    private TenantContext tenantContext;

    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        tenantContext.getIssuerUri(); // <----- exception is thrown
    }
}
```

When I access `tenantContext` in my custom `HttpFilter` the exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.tenantContext': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:383) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at com.c.o.c.model.TenantContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4df4fdfb.setIssuerUri(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.c.o.c.filter.JwtPreAuthorizationConfigurer.doFilter(JwtPreAuthorizationConfigurer.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
```

But if I do the same in `@RestController`-annotated class everything works fine:

```java
@RestController
public class ConsentsController {
    @Resource
    private TenantContext tenantContext;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<ConsentRecord> createConsents(
            @RequestBody CreateConsentRequest createConsents
    ) {
        tenantContext.getTenantName();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
    }
}
```

As far as I understand at the filtering step the request is already bound to a serving thread, so there shouldn't be any exception, should it?

Comment: The filter isn’t a bean in your code. What makes it a spring bean?

Comment: Filters execute before the dispatcher servlet, which manage the scope. YOu would need to register the `RequestContextListener` to make it work outside the scope of the dispatcherservlet.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar it is a bean, see Configuration class

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, with `RequestContextListener` added the issue is gone

Comment: Which was also what the error message was telling you to do (you did read it didn't you?).

Comment: I didn't do it because all the examples with the same error I found were related to usage of @Async, but in my case it's clearly one and the same thread.